# How to get more arrangements out of an equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to converge to the root of this equation

$$2 x^3 + 4 x^2 – 2 x – 5 = 0$$

through 3 different arrangements so far tried 4 and only one worked which is this one

$$(x/2 + 5/4 - 0.5 x^3)^{1/2}$$
some of the arrangements I tried got me to the root after too many iterations (5000~15000) so I ignored them
How to find more arrangements to try?

Answer (score 1):

[Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) gives the iteration
$$
\begin{align}
x_{k+1}
&=x_k-\frac{2x_k^3+4x_k^2–2x_k–5}{6x_k^2+8x_k-2}\tag1\\
&=\frac{4x_k^3+4x_k^2+5}{6x_k^2+8x_k-2}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Iteration $(2)$ could be thought of as a rearrangement since cross multiplication and subtraction gives
$$
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{4x_k^3+4x_k^2+5}{6x_k^2+8x_k-2}\tag3\\
0&=2x^3+4x^2-2x-5\tag4
\end{align}
$$

---

**Computing the Roots**

[image]

Using the iteration in $(2)$ and starting at $x_1\in\left\{1,-1,-2\right\}$ gives
$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
k&x_k\\\hline
1&1\\
2&1.0833333333333333333\\
3&1.0781830462681526511\\
4&1.0781625876515298067\\
5&1.0781625873293308468\\
6&\color{#C00}{1.0781625873293308468}
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
k&x_k\\\hline
1&-1\\
2&-1.2500000000000000000\\
3&-1.3095238095238095238\\
4&-1.3153867041891925251\\
5&-1.3154487998979105398\\
6&-1.3154488069075722138\\
7&-1.3154488069075723031\\
8&\color{#C00}{-1.3154488069075723031}
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
k&x_k\\\hline
1&-2\\
2&-1.8333333333333333333\\
3&-1.7724867724867724868\\
4&-1.7629503938578455289\\
5&-1.7627139251465655298\\
6&-1.7627137804218127461\\
7&-1.7627137804217585437\\
8&\color{#C00}{-1.7627137804217585437}
\end{array}
$$